# Verilog multiplication through repeated addition

Tags: verilog, hardware, synthesis

I need help with a Verilog design I'm doing.

the idea is to do multiplication through repeated addition every time the M bit is set to 1/true.  then I need to output that value.  The assignment statement `F=P;` is throwing the error.

This is the error I'm getting

```
Error (10044): Verilog HDL error at Design2.v(13): expression cannot reference entire array "P"
```

It is my understanding that I can assign a register to an output if they are the same size.  If I'm wrong then how can I implement this?

```
module Design2(A, N, M, F);

input A[7:0];
input N[3:0];
input M;
reg P[15:0];
output F[15:0];

always @(M) begin
    repeat(N) begin
    P = P + A;
    end
    F=P;
end

endmodule
```

Comment: `reg P[15:0];` is an array of 16 single bit entries. `reg [15:0] P;` is a 16-bit wide value.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping apart the logic side, I can see two issues with your design.

1. As the comments pointed out, you have used **unpacked arrays at wrong place**.
2. **Declaration of output port** `F`.

For the **first** issue, the design needs a **16-bit vector** for all the ports and variables. Here, the design takes a **bunch of 8-bits** as **input** `A` which must be declared as `input [7:0] A`, which is a **packed array**. Also, `P` needs to be a vector of size 16-bit in order to have contiguous operations.

This is to be done so that, when the statement `P=P+A` executes, the addition operation is done with **all** the variables taken with their **respective sizes** (size if P=16 and A=8). The overall addition is to be done with 16-bits, padding zeros in MSB side of `A`.

Hence, convert all the variables to **packed array** as follows:

```
  input [7:0] A;
  input [3:0] N;
  input M;
  reg [15:0] P;
  output reg [15:0] F;
```

For the **second** issue, the design assigns output in a **procedural** `always` **block**.

`wire` elements must be continuously driven by something, and cannot store a value. Henceforth, they are assigned values using **continuous assignment statements**.

`reg` can be used to create registers in procedural blocks. Thus, it can **store** some value.

When an `input` port is connected, it has to be driven through **continuous assignments** from parent module, hence `input` ports are **always** `wire`. While `output` from a module can be driven **continuously** through a `wire`, or can be driven through **procedural assignments** through `reg`. Following image shows the port connection rules.

[image: Input/Output Declaration]

To accomplish this in current design, the output port must be **declared** as `output reg [15:0] F`. This is the cause of compilation error shown.

Either way, you can have `output [15:0] F` with no `reg` and make continuous assignment to `F` as follows. This will synthesize `F` to `wire`:

```
output [15:0] F;
assign F=P;
```

SystemVerilog adds a `logic` datatype to remove confusion between usage of `wire` and `reg` declaration. A `logic` can be driven by **both** continuous assignment or blocking/non blocking assignment.

```
// Either continuous assignment
output logic [15:0] F;
assign F=P;

// Or procedural assignment
output logic [15:0] F;
// Inside always block
F=P;
```

For more information on packed and unpacked array, refer [SystemVerilog Arrays](http://electrosofts.com/systemverilog/arrays.html) link. Regarding port declarations, refer [Wire and Net](http://www-inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs150/sp13/resources/Nets.pdf) pdf. Refer SystemVerilog [IEEE 1800-2012](https://blogs.mentor.com/verificationhorizons/blog/2013/02/25/get-your-ieee-1800/) for more information on `logic` datatype.